# Find a string in an other string in PLSQL

Tags: string, plsql, substr

For example I have two strings like these:

string1: JOHN SMITH

string2: workflow john smith123johnsmith

I want to make a flag, by something like this:

case when upper(string2) like '%string1%' then 1 else 0 end

But its not working.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So.. You have the working code, that does what you want. What else do you need? You want to create a function?

Comment: No, its not working.

Comment: well, this part ".. like '%string%' then.." - put it in upper function also.

Comment: but its already uppercased. This is not the solution

Comment: "select
  &string2,
  case when upper(&string2) like upper('%JOHN SMITH%') then 1 else 0 end
 from dual" works fine.

Comment: If you state, that it doesn't work - post your actual code.

Comment: You're trying to compare to '%string1%', which is a string literal not including the value of your variable. You need to concatenate e.g. '%' || string1 || '%'

Comment: Thats it!. It works! Thank you!

Comment: @Looz Using wildcards like `%` in like statement is a killer of performance. Same time if the column has indexes, it wont be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_substr` to do that as below:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN ( regexp_substr(<your_string2> , <your_string1>,1,1,'i')) = lower(<your_string1>)
            then 1
            ELSE
            0
         end   Col
from dual
```

Demo:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN ( regexp_substr('workflow john smith123johnsmith' , 'JOHN SMITH',1,1,'i')) = lower('JOHN SMITH')
            then 1
            ELSE
            0
         end   Col
from dual
```